# ordered (enumerated) dl list, perhaps with css

Tags: html, css

what is the "correct" markup to get a cross between an ol and a dl:

```
<dl>
<dt> one topic </dt> <dd> text </dd>
<dt> another topic </dt> <dd> text </dd>
</dl>
```

and the logical way to display this (perhaps because I have 365 of these, one for each day of the year) is

```
 1. one topic
           text
 2. another topic
           text
```

/iaw

Comment: You could use [CSS2 counters](http://jsfiddle.net/Lux2u/) to style them, but that's a little hacky. What content are you trying to display?

Comment: it's not a specific question.  it's more general.  I have a logical DL, but it also has a natural correspondence to a counter.  say, twelve flowers that bloom in different months of the year.  or, 20 classroom sessions for a 10-week course.  or 150 countries.  or ...

Answer (score 3):

css provides an easy way to do this with a dl

```css
dl {
 counter-reset: term;
}

dt:before {
 counter-increment: term;
 content: counter(term) ". ";
}
```

```html
<dl> 
 <dt>Red</dt>
 <dd>The color at the longer-wavelengths end of the spectrum of visible light next to orange, at the opposite end from violet.</dd>
 <dt>Yellow</dt>
 <dd>The color between green and orange on the spectrum of visible light. It is evoked by light with a predominant wavelength of roughly 570–590 nm.</dd>
 <dt>Blue</dt>
 <dd>The colour between violet and green on the optical spectrum of visible light. Human eyes perceive blue when observing light with a wavelength between 450 and 495 nanometres, which is between 4500 and 4950 ångströms.</dd>
 <dt>Etc.</dt>
    <dd>Many styling options are possible.</dd>
</dl>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `<ol>` and style `ol ol` or `ol ul` to `list-style: none`. Like this:

```html
<ol>
  <li>item 1
    <ul>
      <li>description</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>item 2
    <ul>
      <li>description</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ol>
```

```css
ol ul {
  list-style: none;
}
```

`<ol>` is your wanted **ordered list** - `ul` stands for *unordered* list.

Comment: thanks.  it does the job.  it isn't really a nice simple logical markup---like giving a css property that says "precede with a number."  another alternative is to use <ol> <li> <span class="hdr"> item 1 </span> ... </ol> and style that.  again, not logical, but does the job.

Comment: Well if it solves please don't forget to accept the answer! You can always prepend the number with jQuery but depending on JavaScript for main content isn't optimal.